# When ocmod extension install vqmod not working

Tags: opencart2.x, vqmod, ocmod

I have installed opencart 2.1 and My Vqmod working fine, but when I am trying to install a ocmod extension suddenly vqmod stopped working. Any one know the reason please help me to solve the isuue.

Comment: There is a conflict between your `VQMOD` and the `OCMOD` you have installed. Check `/vqmod/logs` to see the error. Also enable the `error.log` from `System > Settings > Edit Store > Server > Log Errors > Yes`.

Comment: No errors showing.

Comment: Is there a `/system/storage/logs/error.log` & `/system/storage/logs/ocmod.log`? What's inside them?